# number of solutions of $2x^2+7x−5 ≡0 \mod 1099$

Tags: number-theory

number of solutions of $2x^2+7x−5 ≡0  \mod 1099$?

We learned that we can use $b^{2}-4ac$ to check how many solutions there are but in this case 1099 is not prime...

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: **Hint** $\, 7\mid 1099\,$ and it has no roots mod $7$ hence no roots mod $1099\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ 7\!:\,\ f(x)\equiv 2(x^2+1),\ $ but $\ \left[x^{\large 2}\equiv -1\right]^{\large 3}\!\Rightarrow\, x^{\large 6}\equiv -1\,$ contra little Fermat.